# identify this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I inherited a project that includes the following crazy JavaScript. I assume this is the result of running the original code through a minifier/obfuscator, and wasn't actually written like this.

It appears that the original code was the [JCarousel Lite](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCarouselLite) JQuery plugin. Is there any way I can identify which version of this plugin it was? If I knew what was used to obfuscate the code, I guess I could run all versions through the obfuscator and see which one matches (I'm assuming there's no pseudo-randomness in the obfuscation process).

```
eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, r) {
    e = function(c) {
        return(c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36))
    };
    if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
        while (c--)r[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c);
        k = [function(e) {
            return r[e]
        }];
        e = function() {
            return'\\w+'
        };
        c = 1
    }
    ;
    while (c--)if (k[c])p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]);
    return p
}('(6($){$.1g.1w=6(o){o=$.1f({r:n,x:n,N:n,17:q,J:n,L:1a,16:n,y:q,u:12,H:3,B:0,k:1,K:n,I:n},o||{});8 G.R(6(){p b=q,A=o.y?"15":"w",P=o.y?"t":"s";p c=$(G),9=$("9",c),E=$("10",9),W=E.Y(),v=o.H;7(o.u){9.1h(E.D(W-v-1+1).V()).1d(E.D(0,v).V());o.B+=v}p f=$("10",9),l=f.Y(),4=o.B;c.5("1c","H");f.5({U:"T",1b:o.y?"S":"w"});9.5({19:"0",18:"0",Q:"13","1v-1s-1r":"S","z-14":"1"});c.5({U:"T",Q:"13","z-14":"2",w:"1q"});p g=o.y?t(f):s(f);p h=g*l;p j=g*v;f.5({s:f.s(),t:f.t()});9.5(P,h+"C").5(A,-(4*g));c.5(P,j+"C");7(o.r)$(o.r).O(6(){8 m(4-o.k)});7(o.x)$(o.x).O(6(){8 m(4+o.k)});7(o.N)$.R(o.N,6(i,a){$(a).O(6(){8 m(o.u?o.H+i:i)})});7(o.17&&c.11)c.11(6(e,d){8 d>0?m(4-o.k):m(4+o.k)});7(o.J)1p(6(){m(4+o.k)},o.J+o.L);6 M(){8 f.D(4).D(0,v)};6 m(a){7(!b){7(o.K)o.K.Z(G,M());7(o.u){7(a<=o.B-v-1){9.5(A,-((l-(v*2))*g)+"C");4=a==o.B-v-1?l-(v*2)-1:l-(v*2)-o.k}F 7(a>=l-v+1){9.5(A,-((v)*g)+"C");4=a==l-v+1?v+1:v+o.k}F 4=a}F{7(a<0||a>l-v)8;F 4=a}b=12;9.1o(A=="w"?{w:-(4*g)}:{15:-(4*g)},o.L,o.16,6(){7(o.I)o.I.Z(G,M());b=q});7(!o.u){$(o.r+","+o.x).1n("X");$((4-o.k<0&&o.r)||(4+o.k>l-v&&o.x)||[]).1m("X")}}8 q}})};6 5(a,b){8 1l($.5(a[0],b))||0};6 s(a){8 a[0].1k+5(a,\'1j\')+5(a,\'1i\')};6 t(a){8 a[0].1t+5(a,\'1u\')+5(a,\'1e\')}})(1x);', 62, 96, '||||curr|css|function|if|return|ul|||||||||||scroll|itemLength|go|null||var|false|btnPrev|width|height|circular||left|btnNext|vertical||animCss|start|px|slice|tLi|else|this|visible|afterEnd|auto|beforeStart|speed|vis|btnGo|click|sizeCss|position|each|none|hidden|overflow|clone|tl|disabled|size|call|li|mousewheel|true|relative|index|top|easing|mouseWheel|padding|margin|200|float|visibility|append|marginBottom|extend|fn|prepend|marginRight|marginLeft|offsetWidth|parseInt|addClass|removeClass|animate|setInterval|0px|type|style|offsetHeight|marginTop|list|jCarouselLite|jQuery'.split('|'), 0, {}))
// js for widget "Menu"
```

Comment: Judging by the start of the obfuscated code, it was created by [Dean Edwards' Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it was the [Dean Edwards /packer/](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/):

Also -- to see the code deobfuscated, simply replace the `eval` with `alert`.

[This page has a lot of information for deobfuscating.](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/decompress-javascript-compressed-by-packer-and-other-compressors.html)

Comment: +1: this is most definitely. dean edwards packer. one just have to check "Base 64 encode" and "Shrink Variables" thats all

Answer (score 5):

You can use a tool such as http://jsbeautifier.org/ to de-obfuscate the Javascript and as you point out, it's `$.fn.jCarouselLite`.

The code doesn't seem to contain the actual version number of the plugin so you'd have to do a comparison of source code to figure that out.

For reference, here's the source code de-obfuscated: http://jsfiddle.net/78aaX/

Comment: Version numbers are typically in comments - which generally make code larger and better readable: two reasons not to include it in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [JavaScript De-obfuscator FireFox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/) to get the de-obfuscated script.